# Is there a use for non-planar polygons?

Tags: geometry, terminology, applications, polygons

Three points always lie on one (or more, for collinear points) planes, but four or more may not. Is there an application for polygons (with more than three vertices) that do not have vertices that lie on a plane? Do conventional formulas like the sum of internal angles still apply? And is there a term for such polygons?

The only mentions I've found on Google are for CAD software, and how to triangulate them to make them planar.

Comment: Three points always lie in one plane (not "or more").

Comment: What I meant is that three collinear points lie on infinite planes.

Comment: Is there an application for polygons that do not what? Not have all points in the same plane? Those are called polytopes.

Comment: I read that polytopes are higher-dimensional analogues of polygons e.g. polyhedra in 3D. What I mean is still a "2D" shape with one face, such as this skew quadrilateral hyperboloid patch: http://researchgate.net/profile/Emanuel_Huhnen-Venedey/publication/236871716/figure/fig2/AS:299426095616014@1448400152744/Left-A-finite-hyperboloid-patch-Right-A-finite-skew-quadrilateral-on-a-hyperboloid.png

Comment: You could consider piecewise-linear loops.

Comment: Do you mean skew polygons? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_polygon

Answer (score 0):

It may be not exactly what you've searched for, but http://www-video.eecs.berkeley.edu/papers/avz/Two-dimensional%20IEEE%20SP%2092.pdf.